# Automating Salesforce Security Checks

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql, salesforce-chatter

I need to create some automated method for checking certain security settings within a given Salesforce org(s). The four big ones are:

1. IP Restrictions within each profile
2. Mobile User setting disabled
3. Mobile Lite disabled
4. Chatter Disabled

I think the first two can be accomplished through the API (SOQL to get all profiles and check loginIpRanges[] length >0 and SOQL to get all users and check isMobileUser property for each one), but I can't find anything in the API for the other two and wonder if I would have to screen scrape it.

Any suggestions on the best approach to accomplish this? A local Python or other script that connects remotely via the API and a screen scraper or Selenium script for the non-API items? An Apex or VisualForce page that is installed within each org?

I am new to Salesforce and Apex, so before I start down one road and doing it within Salesforce vs via the API I would really appreciate any guidance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to take a mixed approach to solving this, perhaps wrapped up in some larger python script.

- Use the metadata API to get all of the Profile objects and parse for loginIPRanges. You can use Apache ANT and the Force.com migration tool commands to do this. You can also get the SecuritySettings from the same API and method and get a lot of the things in the Security Health Check, if you need them. The results will be returned in XML, which you can easily parse in your python script.
- Use the API and a SOQL query to check for the isMobileUser permission, use python to parse/output results. Beatbox is a good library for connecting to the standard API.
- For the last two, I think you'll need to go with some screen scraping/browser automation and parsing. Hopefully someone has a better answer for this, as I'm not familiar enough to help with how to accomplish this aspect. The screens are in standard locations so it should be repeatable as long as future updates don't move things.

Ideally you'll be able to combine these into one large script that fires off beatbox, then fires off ant/migration tool, and some browser automation script.